# Private comments in JIRA issues

Tags: jira

I want to enable my team to add comments to issues that can only be seen by my team for the purpose of private conversations related to the issue. For example, to facilitate conversation about the technical requirements for fulfilling the request, or to allow new team members to comment "Hey Joe, I don't know how to do this, can you show me?", without the reporter being able to see those comments. I had this at a former employer, so I know it can be done, but I don't know how to set it up myself.

Comment: Isn't that a feature of Jira Servicedesk?  I don't believe the facility is available in Jira core or Jira Software.   Maybe a plugin: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/search?application=jira&category=&cost=&hosting=&marketingLabel=&q=comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by creating a new Role of "Team Members", giving that Role the permissions to Comment, and then going into my project and defining that Role as my team's group. Now, when they comment they get the little open padlock icon under the comment that they can click and select "Team Members", and then only we can see the comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by setting the [viewing restrictions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira064/commenting-on-an-issue-720416302.html#CommentingonanIssue-Addingacomment) while creating a comment. Your admin may also need to configure the [comment visibility](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira064/configuring-jira-options-720411998.html) settings first.